# What is the difference between tuning the speed on the Ender 3 panel, and the Cura Print Speed setting?

Tags: creality-ender-3, ultimaker-cura

I'm printing a lot of draft parts so I don't care if they fall apart in my fingers, I just need the shape. I can scroll to the Tune menu on my Ender 3 Pro console and set the speed to 200% and it doubles the speed. But when I set the Print Speed setting to 100 instead of 50 mm/s in Cura, it doesn't save much time, even if I adjust the individual first layer speed, wall speed, top layer speed, etc. What is the difference?

Ideally, I would like the first layer to print normally, and then print at 2x speed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

Feed rate, in general, is the speed of a single print move, from point A to point B. It is specified with every [G1 command](https://marlinfw.org/docs/gcode/G000-G001.html) that commands a move. Setting the feed rate on the printer console will scale the feed rate of every move the printer makes. The Cura "Print speed" setting is used as a basis to set the print speed (Feed rate) of different line types. Eg. Infil is 100% of this speed, walls are 50% of this speed, etc.

There are several other settings that will make Cura will decide not to use the speed that you set.

- Minimum layer time. In my case, this prevented the walls of the calibration cube from reaching the maximum speed. They were slowed down until so that each layer took at least 10 seconds.
- Lines that overhangs are scaled to a percentage of what they would normally print at.
- Bridge speed settings are found in the experimental settings, and if enabled they will override the speed for bridges.

In addition, the printer's acceleration setting may prevent it from reaching the maximum speed. You can see this if you issue this command during printing:

```
M201 X50 Y50 ; Set max acceleration
```

The print will slow down a lot until you set it back to the default. The printer will accelerate and decelerate slowly and simply never reach the maximum speed over short distances. The default in the Marlin firmware (for Ender) seems to be:

```
M201 X500 Y500 ; Set max acceleration
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look under Cura setting to set ' Initial Layer Print Speed ' and ' Initial Layer Travel speed ', you may appropriately set you print speed as you required